# "logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[10,2] labels_size=[10,11]"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am building a machine learning model that is using data of tumors to classify other tumors. However, there seems to be a problem when I declare the cost.

I don't get why this is a problem, because I ran this same exact code with the MNIST data set provided by TensorFlow, and it worked fine. In that case, I had set my n_classes to 10, batch_size to 100, and `x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])`.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified the number of classes as 2:

```
n_classes = 2
```

So your output layer is shape `[10, 2]`, when using a batch of 10 as you've specified. But you're passing 11 labels per sample, giving you a label shape of `[10, 11]`. You're probably passing your data in as your labels in your `sess.run([...], feed_dict={...})`. You didn't specify the shape of your labels:

```
y = tf.placeholder('float')
```

That line should to be:

```
y = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, n_classes])
```

If you do that I expect that your error will move to your `sess.run` call and it will point out that you're passing in the wrong data for your labels.

Also, as a side note, for a binary predictor, you'll get slightly better results if you use a single neuron on the output. Although it works to use 2 neurons for a binary class, it usually performs slightly worse than a single [0,1] output class.

Comment: So I added what you said to my y variable and the new error I receive is 'Cannot feed value of shape (10, 11) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Comment: Print the value of the data you're passing into tensorflow. Why are you passing in a matrix of size [batch_size x 11] for your labels? You have 2 classes right? Shouldn't you be passing in a value of size [batch_size x 2]? The problem is outside of tensorflow, what you are passing to tensorflow appears to be wrong.

Comment: Also, add a name property to your placeholders, such as `y = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, n_classes], name='y')`. That way the error message won't read 'Placeholder_1:0', it will read 'y' and the bug will be more easily apparent to you.

Comment: I am inputting 11 features into the neural net, which then outputs either benign or malignant, which is why I was feeding in 11. But is this incorrect?

Comment: Your labels are 2 values: {1,0}, your inputs are 11 features. Your `y` placeholder should be getting something of size [batch_size, 2] right? Your `x` placeholder should be getting 11 features, size [batch_size, 11]. Why is your `y` placeholder apparently getting 11 feature? This looks like a bug, it looks like you are passing in your inputs to your `y` labels placeholder by accident. Add names to all of your tensors, it makes it much easier to understand the errors.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I changed this and I am still getting the error 'Cannot feed value of shape (10, 11) for Tensor 'y:0', which has shape '(10, 2)'. Would it help if I attached the full code? It may be an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Just before your call to `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={y:labels,x:features})` run `print(labels)`. You see something of the shape [10, 11] right? It should be [10, 2]. You might want to post your code so we can point out exactly where the issue is. And by all means, post the result of printing out the data you're trying to pass into tensorflow at this point.

Comment: When I print y, it gives a shape of [10,2]. Let me post my full code; you may find the cause somewhere else. The new code has been added above.

Comment: `Y_random = data[idxs]`, you're loading your data into Y_random here, then you randomize it with `epoch_Y = Y_random[i * batch_size:(i+1) * batch_size]`, the shape of both `Y_random` and `epoch_Y` is [batch_size, 11] is it not? It sure looks like you're loading your feature data into your labels right there. Are you sure you printed `epoch_Y` and saw that it had shape [batch_size, 2]??? It looks pretty clear to me that `X_random == Y_random` and it most certainly should not.

Comment: Where should I print epoch_y? Because if I print it after the for loop, the error already arises by then, and if I print it above the for loop, it says that I am referencing it before assigning it.

Comment: Your bug is here: `X_random = data[idxs]`, `Y_random = data[idxs]`. Your labels do not equal your inputs. I don't know how to be more clear. Put a print statement immediately before sess.run if the problem isn't obvious to you yet. Grab a debugger and breakpoint at sess.run and inspect the variables just before you pass them into sess.run. This is a simple debugging issue at this point.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying, but why would my labels equal my inputs? If I have 11 input nodes into my network, and want to output one of two things, why would these two equal each other? The labels are basically the outputs right?

Comment: That's your bug, they should certainly not be equal. You are not passing in any labels. Fix that.

Comment: Here's a really simple neural network example, it might be worth going through this in detail to understand what's going on and what things should look like. https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.ipynb

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look at this resource and tell you how it goes!

Comment: So I've looked over the resource you gave me, and tried to fix the issue, but it is simply not working. I understand that the error occurs in the 'for epoch in range' loop. Is the next_batch command used in the TensorFlow MNIST example a form of back propagation?

Comment: Do you agree that your label should have 2 values and your data should have 11 values? If so, let's simplify then. Set your batch size to 1. Now set a breakpoint immediately before your `sess.run` call, you could add: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. That will kick you into a command line debugger just before you call sess.run. In the debugger type `epoch_X` and `epoch_Y` to print the values you're passing to tensorflow. Paste the results to a comment here (to the extent that they fit the space for comments).

Comment: Could you point me to an IDE with this capability? The one I have right now is Wing101, which is kind of like a free version of Wing IDE. It doesn't seem to have breakpoint capabilities. I have also tried Exedore, but there are compatibility issues with tensorflow.

Comment: By all means use PyCharm community edition. But python comes with a command line debugger, `pdb`, just copy that line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into your code and run it, it'll drop you into a command line debugger. Try it, it's really simple. But for python debugging help please open another question, this has become too long and should not be continued as a long running thread, it's not good stackoverflow form to have run-on comments.

Comment: Ok so in the debugger: epoch_x = [[  1.32007700e+06   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]] epoch_y = [[  1.32007700e+06   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00]]

Comment: Yes, those are the same, that's your problem, the point I've been making all along. You're missing something truly fundamental here. Your epoch_x should be your INPUT, your epoch_y should be your LABELS. Those two things CANNOT be the same (unless you're doing an Autoencoder, which you're not). If it's not obvious to you why those should not be the same you should back up and work through a few tutorials to understand the basic concepts better.

Comment: I actually got it working, thanks. I'm fixing another issue now with my loss coming up as nan.